# Ubuntu Server hung?

Tags: server, ssh, nextcloud, cockpit

Yesterday, March 20, around 6-7 p.m., my Ubuntu server did something strange, cockpit would not log me in with an internal error, nextcloud also with an internal error.
I restarted it and it did not accept connections even through ssh, at the same time it did by magic. I have been looking at the syslog and there is an outage from the 20th at 7 p.m. to the 21st at 4 p.m., I can't find the reason why. Is this normal?

Comment: I experienced server hangs some time ago, and I had to change the ram to ECC-memory - this fixed the crashes for me.

Comment: Interesting, because of the memory the syslog stops writing but Apache continues to work but without being able to log in?

Comment: I can just say that when I experienced issues it was strange, because some processes froze, and some seemed to work - for me the logging worked.

Comment: Here are the issues I posted about this. Note that for [the first issue](https://github.com/prometheus/node_exporter/issues/2420), the server crashed completely (and this happened several times many days in a row). For [the second issue](https://github.com/prometheus/node_exporter/issues/2467) (after I switched to ECC memory), the process crashed, but restarted afterwards without affecting the server in a major way.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to debug your issue further when you have no logs with details. Even for my issue, the conclusion was that it was probably memory errors, and switching to ECC memory fixed it for me.